# Retreiving a list of entities through a generated Jersey REST client

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, vaadin

Iam having trouble receiving list of entities from a rest service.

I generated a Jersey REST client through netbeans and Iam using it like this to retrieve a single entity. (this works)

agentDTO - is a data transfer object

agentCli - is the generated client

`agentDTO a = agentCli.find_JSON(agentDTO.class, "5");`

This doesn't work and crashes.

```
List<agentDTO> tList = new ArrayList<agentDTO>();
               tList = agentCli.findAll_JSON(List.class);
```

Comment: what is your issue ?

Comment: Can you paste the "crash" report? Error message?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The fault lies with oracle. Made a local database and it works just fine now.

Also, instead of the default findAll_JSON I use this method in the client:

```
 public List<agentDTO> getAgents() {
    Response serviceResponse
            = client.target(BASE_URI + "/agent/").
            request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Response.class);
    List<agentDTO> agents = serviceResponse.readEntity(new GenericType<List<agentDTO>>() {
    });
    return agents;
}
```